# recreacion imagen volley imageloader

Tags: imagen, android-imageview, android-volley

```
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        int cacheSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4 MegaBytes
        LruCache<String, Bitmap> lruCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize);
        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return lruCache.get(url);
        }
        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            lruCache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });

    //asigna la imagen de perfil del usuario
    NetworkImageView.setImageUrl(Constantes.PROFILEPIC, imageLoader);
```

Como puedo evitar que cada vez que me entra a la actividad me vuelva a crear la imagen, si ya esta creada?, quisiera que hubiera un condicional o algo que me verifique si ya he creado la imagen, de esta manera puede que me cargue mucho mas rapido

Comment: Hola Jesus, porque ImageLoader y no ImageRequest?

Comment: como seria con imagerequest? el codigo lo saque de internet, por eso lo uso